# DataTable not populating - instead regular api response

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, datatable

i have been trying to populate a reponsive dataTable with the result of an axaj call. However when i submit the request i receive a blank page with only the reponse entities.

Here is my bean that i retrieve after the api has done it's job:

```
  private String validator;
  private String validThrough;
  private String creator;
  private String createdOn;
  private String profile;
  private String token;
  private String profileType;
  private String status;
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('.smart-form');
    var counter = 0;
   form.submit(function (e) {
       if (counter != 0) {
           $("#datatable_col_reorder").dataTable().fnDestroy();
           counter++;
       }
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax ( {
           url: form.attr('action'), dataSrc: "", "data": {
               "validator": $('#searchValidator').val(),
               "validFrom": $('#searchValidFrom').val(),
               "validTo": $('#searchValidTo').val(),
               "creator": $('#searchCreator').val()
               "createdOn": $('#searchCreatedOn').val()
               "profile": $('#searchProfile').val()
               "token": $('#searchToken').val()
               "profileType": $('#searchSelectType').val()
           },
           success: function (data) 
           {
            jQuery.noConflict();
               var table =$('#datatable_col_reorder').DataTable ( {
                   data:data,
                   columns: [
                       {"data": "validator"},
                       {"data": "validThrough"},
                       {"data": "creator"}, 
                       {"data": "createdOn"},
                       {"data": "profile"},
                       {"data": "token"},
                       {"data": "profileType"},
                       {"data": "status"}
                   ],
                  bDestroy: true
               });
           }
       }); 
   });
    });
```

I just receive this:

```
[{"validator":"ЧъкНорис","validThrough":"2019-06-09 12:55:48.0-2019-06-09 12:55:48.0","creator":"ЧъкНорис","createdOn":"2019-06-09 12:55:48.0","profile":"ProfileAlumni","token":"QWERTYUI","profileType":"1","status":"Inactive"},{"validator":"ЧъкНорис","validThrough":"2019-06-09 12:55:48.0-2019-06-09 12:55:48.0","creator":"ЧъкНорис","createdOn":"2019-06-09 12:55:48.0","profile":"ProfileAlumni","token":"QWERTYUI","profileType":"1","status":"Inactive"}]
```

My page dissapears and i just have the response, which is not the behavior im looking for.
I have checked whether the names of my reponse is the same as the table columns but this is not the problem.

I checked all the selectors it's i believe they are all correct:

```
<table id="datatable_col_reorder"
                            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                            width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>validator</th>
                                    <th>validThrough</th>
                                    <th>creator</th>
                                    <th>createdOn</th>
                                    <th>profile</th>
                                    <th>token</th>
                                    <th>profileType</th>
                                    <th>status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Sounds like you either have errors being thrown and the submit listener never gets added to form....or the form doesn't exist when code shown runs...or selector for form is incorrect

Comment: Hello @charlietfl i have added the table im trying to populate. Its pretty simple so i doubt i have mistaken any of the id's or classes.

Comment: OK.. but it sounds like form is submitting using default form process and then loading the response from it's `action` url. So it's the `form.submit` that is a problem. Are there any errors in browser dev tools console? Does form exist on page load etc

Comment: Actually just now i had the same though and i think you are correct! I placed an alert right after the form.submit - alert('hi mom'); and it never displays, so it does not go in the method at all! 
As far as errors go i have one that says(Unexpected string) error on row 580 - but my file has 400 rows overall which is weird

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, the issue was that i have missed the colons after the data selection :

```
 "validator": $('#searchValidator').val(),
           "validFrom": $('#searchValidFrom').val(),
           "validTo": $('#searchValidTo').val(),
           "creator": $('#searchCreator').val() <---- should be a colon
           "createdOn": $('#searchCreatedOn').val() <---- should be a colon 
           "profile": $('#searchProfile').val() <---- should be a colon
           "token": $('#searchToken').val() <---- should be a colon
           "profileType": $('#searchSelectType').val()
```